# How to get results each sec from "perf stat -d sleep 1000"

Tags: performance, events, stat, perf

Is there any way to get the "perf stat -d sleep 1000" command to update me about the events value every 1/2/3 second(s) during a long time?
I tried it on PAPI and I made it but the problem is that I'm limited to 4/5 events max on an eventset... so I cant get that much info that I need. 
The problem about "perf stat" is that I dont want to get a final report for a X time but I want to see the evolution of the value events like how LLC-misses changes when I run a benchmark software etc..

any idea?

Comment: what does `-d` do?  I didn't see that in the man page for my version of perf stat.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the `--interval-print` flag if you have a new enough version of perf:

```
-I msecs, --interval-print msecs
       Print count deltas every N milliseconds (minimum: 100ms) example:
       perf stat -I 1000 -e cycles -a sleep 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use -I specific perf option to print the results every 1,2,3,etc seconds.

```
perf stat -a -r 1 -e power/energy-pkg/ -I 1000
```

This command prints system-wide statistics of the energy-pkg plane every 1 second. You can find more examples in the following link: http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html